# Can anyone solve $P(A|B)\leq P(A) \implies P(A|B^c)\geq P(A)$?

Tags: probability

Does anyone know how to prove $P(A|B)\leq P(A) \implies P(A|B^c)\geq P(A)$ ?
It is from the book "introduction to probability"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the law of total probability and our hypothesis we have
$$P(A) = P(A \mid B)P(B) + P(A \mid B^c)P(B^c) \leq P(A)P(B) + P(A \cap B^c).$$

Hence,
$$ P(A)(1 - P(B)) \leq P(A \cap B^c) $$

Since $1 - P(B) = P(B^c)$,

$$P(A) \leq \frac{P(A \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} = P(A \mid B^c). $$

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

$P(A\mid B)\leq  P(A)
\\ \Updownarrow \text{ (if $P(B)\neq 0$)} \\
P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)P(B)
\\ \Updownarrow \\
P(A)-P(A\cap B^\complement)\leq P(A)\,(1-P(B^\complement))
\\ \Updownarrow \\
\\ \ddots \\$

Comment: it starts with $P(A|B)≤P(A)$. I guess it doesn't matter since we can just flip the sign to another direction.

Comment: @Newbornalive Yes, indeed.